# atomic.excchange for Java

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, queue, atomic

I am attempting to code a generalized concurrent queue in Java (Herb Sutter - http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/writing-a-generalized-concurrent-queue/211601363). I am a little stuck in converting

consumerLock.exchange(true)

to Java. Conceptually, I think I understand what the exchange call does

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/exchange/

Could anyone help me?

Thanks,

Alex Donnini

I don't think AtomicBoolean would work. Did you read the Herb Sutter article I pointed to above? He seems to suggest that in Java the variables would need to be volatile (which makes sense to me). If you read the code:

```
 void Produce( const T& t ) {
    Node* tmp = new Node( new T(t) );
    while( producerLock.exchange(true) )
      { }   // acquire exclusivity
    last->next = tmp;        // publish to consumers
    last = tmp;             // swing last forward
    producerLock = false;       // release exclusivity
  }
```

the statement I am having trouble with is the "while" statement.

I don't think replacing it with

while(producerLock == true)

is correct.

I guess I could write my own exchange method (which would means that I would need the java equivalent of load()) but I was hoping for something simpler

I take it back. AtomicBoolean may be the way to go.

```
    AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);
     if(lock.compareAndSet(false, true)){
         try {
             //do something
         } catch(Exception e){
        //error handling
         } finally {
             lock.set(false);
         }
     }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using AtomicBoolean. It works